# Locating a button one more time, whose text has been changed by an User click

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've located a button, first time around when it is rendered with a text on it as 'Kill' with---> `.//tr[1]/td[4]/div/button[text()='Kill']`.

My html was like...

```html
<tbody>
<tr class="GPBYFDECG GPBYFDEJG" __gwt_row="0" __gwt_subrow="0">
<td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG GPBYFDEEG GPBYFDEKG">
<td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG GPBYFDEKG">
<td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG GPBYFDEKG">
<td class="GPBYFDEBG GPBYFDEDG cellkillbutton GPBYFDEKG">
<div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-339" tabindex="0">
<button type="button" style="width: 50px;color:white;" tabindex="-1">Kill</button>
</div>
</td>
```

When user clicks on the button, the text on it just changes to 'UnKill' and nothing in HTML changes, but when I modify the xpath to 
`.//tr[1]/td[4]/div/button[text()='UnKill']`.
It doesn't work at all. Why ? Even when I refresh the page and go in to the firebug and check it, it does not work.

Comment: Did you inspect the Unkill element and verify that it has the same XPath? I would suggest that you just use `"//button[.='Kill']"` and then `"//button[.='UnKill']"`. I'm guessing these will work because you haven't specified all the required descendants. In general, you don't want to specify so many levels in an XPath, it makes it more brittle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time there might be chances that your element state get changed if you are doing actions with same element . So for your case if it is doing click on button labeled as "Kill"

then check that your button is clickable or not by putting some `ExplicitWait` like

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//tr[1]/td[4]/div/button[contains(text(),'Kill')]")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[1]/td[4]/div/button[contains(text(),'Kill')]")).click();
```

Comment: It is my mistake. The case is important. The spelling of 'Unkill' is NOT 'UnKill', but 'Unkill'. This caused the problem. My xpath was OK. Thanks anyways,

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the button as "Kill" it becomes hidden and some other button gets activated at the same UI location with the text "UnKill". In this case the xpath for this two elements are different. For your second run try finding the xpath of the button/element with text "Unkill" & try to click. It should work.

Comment: No. The xpath is the same except the text is Unkill. I wrongly expected it to be "UnKill". A difference of lower case 'K'. The same xpath worked. That is.//tr[1]/td[4]/div/button[contains(text(),'Unkill')]